# How to start flask api server in separate thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, process, pyqt5

I am working on a python project which includes `pyqt5` and `flask` based API. In the UI, there is `start` and `stop` button which when pressed will start the `flask` api server and stop when clicked on stop button.

```
from server import start_local_server
from multiprocessing import Process

"""
SOME CODE
"""

def start_server_btn_event(self):
    p1 = Process(target=start_local_server())
    p1.start()
    

def stop_server_btn_event(self):
    # Code to stop the api server
```

But doing above is making the whole UI unresponsive and I am not able to click on any other object on UI. How can I run the api server on button click in separate thread or process so that other UI objects are active and can perform their functions. Thanks

Minimal Reproducible Example:

**app.py : This contains pyqt5 button which starts the local server**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from server import start_local_server
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from multiprocessing import Process


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        start_btn = QPushButton('Start Server', self)
        start_btn.move(100, 70)
        start_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_click_start_btn)

        stop_btn = QPushButton('Stop Server', self)
        stop_btn.move(200, 70)
        stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_click_stop_btn)

        fun_btn = QPushButton('Click to check responsiveness', self)
        fun_btn.move(150, 100)
        fun_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_click_fun_btn)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click_start_btn(self):
        # Start server here
        p1 = Process(target=start_local_server())
        p1.start()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click_stop_btn(self):
        print("Stop server ")

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click_fun_btn(self):
        print('If it is working, this means UI is responsive')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**server.py: This is the flask api server code**

```
import os
import datetime
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
wsgi_app = app.wsgi_app


@app.route('/api/status')
def check_status():
    return jsonify({'status': 'ok', 'date': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()}), 200


def start_local_server():

    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, 80)
```

Comment: As the documentation says: "the [join] method blocks until the process [...] terminates". No blocking function should ever happen in the main Qt thread. Why do you call it?

Comment: @musicamante Sorry I had different understanding of the `join`. I have removed it but the UI is still unresponsive

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante I have updated the code with minimal reproducible example. Please have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: @SAndrew Typo: change `p1 = Process(target=start_local_server())` to `p1 = Process(target=start_local_server)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for pointing it out. I am working on it.

Comment: I have provided minimal reproducible example but not sure why the question is downvoted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by starting a separate thread to run API server:

```
run = True


def start_api_server():
    while run:
        start_local_server()
        
    time.sleep(1)
    print("SERVER HAS STOPPED")

@pyqtSlot()
def on_click_start_btn(self):
    Thread(target=start_api_server).start()
```